# Why isnt the Stroke Color changing?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to change the border of a TextButton when the localplayer token.Value is more than cost.value and the same when is less than the token.Value.

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local button = script.Parent
button.UIStroke.GreenUiGradien.Enabled = false
button.UIStroke.RedUiGradient.Enabled = false

local UpgradeOptions = {
    { multiplier = 1, cost = 2 },
    { multiplier = 1.3, cost = 5 },
    .........
}

local tokens = player.leaderstats.Tokens.Value
local tokensUpgradeIndex = player.xMultipliers.TokensUpgradeIndex.Value

local function updateBorder()
    local option = UpgradeOptions[player.xMultipliers.TokensUpgradeIndex.Value]
    local cost = option.cost

    if cost <= player.leaderstats.Tokens.Value then
        button.UIStroke.RedUiGradient.Enabled = true
        button.UIStroke.GreenUiGradien.Enabled = false
    else
        button.UIStroke.RedUiGradient.Enabled = false
        button.UIStroke.GreenUiGradien.Enabled = true
    end
end

updateBorder()

player.leaderstats.Tokens.Changed:Connect(updateBorder) -- Remove the parentheses here
```

At the End the UiStroke isnt even Red or Green. It is Black.

This way works perfectly but i want a gradient which i can set the rotation.

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local button = script.Parent
local greenGradient = ColorSequence.new{
    ColorSequenceKeypoint.new(0, Color3.fromRGB(0, 255, 0)),
    ColorSequenceKeypoint.new(1, Color3.fromRGB(26, 93, 26))
}

local redGradient = ColorSequence.new{
    ColorSequenceKeypoint.new(0, Color3.fromRGB(170, 0, 0)),
    ColorSequenceKeypoint.new(1, Color3.fromRGB(85, 0, 0))
}

local UpgradeOptions = {
    { multiplier = 1, cost = 2 },
    { multiplier = 1.3, cost = 5 },
    ......
}

local tokens = player.leaderstats.Tokens.Value
    local tokensUpgradeIndex = player.xMultipliers.TokensUpgradeIndex.Value

local function updateBorder()
    local option = UpgradeOptions[player.xMultipliers.TokensUpgradeIndex.Value]
    local cost = option.cost
    
    if cost <= player.leaderstats.Tokens.Value then
        button.UIStroke.ColorSequence = Color3.new(1, 0, 0)
    else
        button.UIStroke.Color = Color3.new(0, 0.666667, 0)
        }
    end
end

updateBorder()

player.leaderstats.Tokens.Changed:Connect(updateBorder) -- Remove the parentheses here
```

Comment: this way worked.  if cost >= player.leaderstats.Tokens.Value then
  button.UIStroke.Color = Color3.fromRGB(255, 0, 0)
  button.UIStroke.RedUiGradient.Enabled = true
  button.UIStroke.GreenUiGradien.Enabled = false
 else
  button.UIStroke.Color = Color3.fromRGB(0, 255, 0)
  button.UIStroke.GreenUiGradien.Enabled = true
  button.UIStroke.RedUiGradient.Enabled = false
 end